# Automate the creation of B2C tenant and register the application in that B2C tenant through terraform as well as well Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have one scenario where I have to automate the creation of B2C tenant then register the application as well as Azure AD B2C Custom Policies with the Identity Experience Framework (IEF) to that B2C tenant. this all should be done through the terraform and azure pipeline.

I have created Azure pipeline to run terraform code and service principal also created for the same to connect with azure AD of Parent directory where Azure AD B2C tenant has to be created.

I was using service principle to create Azure AD B2C tenant and I have given  owner permission to that service principle to create Azure AD B2C tenant but we were getting error. While studying some Microsoft documentation I have found  below statement :

"To create Azure AD B2C tenant we must use azure resource manager API.
User_impersonation scope is required which means that user account must be
used instead of service principal to create azure AD B2C tenant"

According to above statement if we are creating B2C tenant using user account which is created in azure AD of parent directory then that user account will inherit the permission from parent directory and become global administrator in B2C tenant but service principal can not become global administrator.

Please let me know how can we use user account with service connection of ADO  instead of using service principal so that we can use user account through service connection with azure Devops pipeline.

It would be great help if I get some reference for B2C automation.

Comment: have you tried the suggestion below and did it work for you? Feel free to let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

What service connection you are using? Is it an ARM SC? ARM SC only supports Service Principal Authentication or an Azure managed Service Identity.

To deploy a B2C tenant in DevOps pipeline, you can try to login to Azure via [az login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login) command and define a B2C tenant via a Bicep file, then run [az deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli#deployment-scope) to deploy the tenant.

A sample Bicep file: `B2CTenant.bicep`

```
resource b2cDirectory 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2021-04-01' = {
  #disable-next-line no-hardcoded-location
  location: 'Australia'
  name: 'YourDirectoryName'
  sku: {
    name: 'PremiumP2'
    tier: 'A0'
  }
  properties: {
    createTenantProperties: {
      countryCode: 'AU'
      displayName: 'YourDisplayName'
    }
  }
  tags: {
    Department: 'Dev'
  }
}
```

Add a PowerShell task in your pipeline.

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   az login --username YourUserName -p YourPassword
   az deployment group create --resource-group YourResourceGroupName --template-file B2CTenant.bicep
  workingDirectory: The directory holding your bicep file
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Replace the values of "username", "password", "resource-group", "template-file" and "workingDirectory".

See [this ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1386649/would-it-be-possible-to-create-an-azure-ad-b2c-ten) and [this blog](https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/bicep-azure-ad-b2c/) for more info.