# How to register application in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I have an azure subscription and I have created a b2c tenant inside the suscription. I am trying to create a terraform script to register applications and custom policies inside the B2C tenant that I created previously. However, I am using a service principal credentials in provider block for deploying the resources in Azure. But, when I try to deploy the app registration I am facing a error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SraNc.png)

I tried to deploy with service principal credentials but I unable to achieve that. Do I need to give any specific permission to my service principal to register an application in B2C tenant?

Comment: please share the terraform configuration you tried @Rajan.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to [add API permissions for the application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_configuration) from Microsoft Graph (Application.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Application.ReadWrite.All).

You need to use the azuread provider (azuread_application) to [create the app registration in B2C](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application.html).

Then need to manually create the service principal and then use the service principal to create the application, as shown [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/175):

```
resource "azuread_application" "yourapp" {
  name                       = "yourapp"
  homepage                   = "https://yourapp"
  reply_urls                 = ["https://yourapp"]
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = true
}
```

Related questions:

[Automate the creation of B2C tenant and register the application in that B2C tenant through terraform as well as well Azure devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364635/automate-the-creation-of-b2c-tenant-and-register-the-application-in-that-b2c-ten)

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issue

[How to configure Azure AD B2C tenant using Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74278248/how-to-configure-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-using-terraform)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/620463/using-a-terraform-service-principal-to-manage-an-a?cid=kerryherger